# How can I remove connections in Visual Studio "Copy Web Site" tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 has a Copy Web Site tool that remembers previous FTP locations that files have been copied to. There is a "Connections" drop down where they are listed. I'd like to remove some old listings from that, but I can't find where they're stored.

I've looked at the solution file, and there's nothing there.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://csc-technicalnotes.blogspot.com/2009/02/remove-connections-from-mru-of-visual.html

Comment: Somebody downvoted this accepted answer FIVE YEARS after it was written, without leaving a comment.