# How can I remove connections in Visual Studio “Copy Web Site” tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio **2013** has a Copy Web Site tool that remembers previous FTP locations that files have been copied to. There is a "Connections" drop down where they are listed. I'd like to remove some old listings from that, but I can't find where they're stored. (question copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001602/how-can-i-remove-connections-in-visual-studio-copy-web-site-tool), changing the version number to 2013)

I've found solutions for removing or deleting remote web site connections from the Copy Web Site wizard in Visual Studio 2008 (such as [this similar one from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001602/how-can-i-remove-connections-in-visual-studio-copy-web-site-tool)), but they don't appear to work in VS2013.

Things I've tried:

1. C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\[Web Site Name]\PublishState.xml doesn't exist.  The WebsiteCache folder isn't there.
2. C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ doesn't seem to have any file that contains the text of the path of the old remote location.  (searched with BareGrep)
3. I've searched the registry for the path of the old remote location and couldn't find it in the registry.
4. I've tried reconnecting to the site after deleting the folder.  VS2013 recognizes that the remote folder no longer exists and asks if I want to create it, but doesn't give me the option of just removing the connection from the list.
5. I've tried highlighting the item in the dropdown list and pressing the Delete key (similar to the way to remove an auto-complete email address from Outlook 2013), but that didn't work either.
6. Various Google searches and StackOverflow searches (which is where I found the article I linked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error.  The previous question and answer for this targeted Visual Studio 2008 using paths for Windows XP.  I'm on Windows 7 and incorrectly translated `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\` to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\`.

I was able to find the PublishState.xml file in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\<siteName>\PublishState.xml`.

As was stated in the previous answer (for VS2008), here are the steps to remove the remote connection.

1. From the Copy Web Site wizard, select the remote connection and click the Disconnect button.  ([MSDN VS2008 Copy Web Site: Removing a Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c95809c0(v=vs.90).aspx))
2. Close Visual Studio 2013.  This updates the PublishState.xml file.
3. Optional: Make a backup copy of the PublishState.xml file.
4. Open `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\<siteName>\PublishState.xml`.
5. Delete the appropriate `<RemoteSite>` and `<PublishStatus>` sections (near the end of the file).
6. Optional: Change the value of the `<ActiveRemoteSiteId>` (near the beginning of the file) to one of the remaining RemoteSite SiteId values.

As a side note, when I re-created the link to one remote site it gave it a different name than the folder paths that the others had.  It gave it a name of `http://localhost:<port>`.  At one point in the past I had mistakenly opened that remote site with Visual Studio and executed the debugger.  This added it to the Microsoft WebMatrix list of sites even though it didn't actually work. I deleted the remote site from Visual Studio as shown above then opened Microsoft Web Matrix, clicked on My Sites, clicked on See All My Sites, found the site and deleted it (taking care to only delete the reference in WebMatrix and not the files from the remote server as well).  When I added that connection again, it used the folder path instead of the WebMatrix name for it.